Calculating Ranking on a large set of data(4000+) that changes depending on the date range selected and orderby
I have a large set of data, 4000 rows+. each row is associated with metric data that is collected daily. Metric table is at over 1.1 million rows.
for example:
Item table:



Id
Item




1
Hello


2
World


...
...



Metric table:



Id
ItemId
CreatedDate
Metric 1
Metric 2




1
1
2024-04-20
34
21


2
1
2024-04-21
54
12


3
1
2024-04-22
32
23


4
2
2024-04-20
53
43


5
2
2024-04-21
54
23


6
2
2024-04-22
12
45


...
...
...
...
...



I need to display the item table to users with an additional column that is Rank and the rank would be based off of the average of Metric 1 data, whats compounding the problem is that users can order by columns and set a date range.
To calculate the rank, i have done the following:

Get all items and their metric data within a date range
Calculate the average Metric 1 value for each item
Order by the average, the index would give us a rank to associate with an item
If the user orders the view table by average of Metric 2, the rank of items wouldn't change

Whilst this works as expected, it is computationally very expensive and takes a long time as it has to iterate over 4000 rows + a set of metrics for each, to further add to this there is an indicator to say whether its gone up or down in rank by comparing the current date range(e.g. 7 day range) with its previous date range(e.g. previous 7 days) this effectively doubles the load.
The data is on a SQL server.
Is there anyway to either make this more performant/faster for the user?
The main problem for me is that there are too many changeable variables to be able to cache/store values.
Being able to filter by a daterange, means i cant store the data and calculations have to be done inline.
What i have works and meets requirements however it is very slow, 40 seconds give or take.
For more common requests such as page load, there is cache that is prebuilt.
Which works but again, should the user change the orderby value or daterange it would have to calculate everything.
Are there any technologies available that speed this kind of process up?
Are there any methods in which data can be stored differently to speed the calculation process up?
EDIT
Project written in .Net core, using Entity Framework
Rough sudo code for EF query:
var dateRangeQuery = FROM Metrics in DB.Metrics 
WHERE CreatedDate > FromDate AND CreatedDate < ToDate
GROUP Metrics BY Metrics.ItemId
INTO Result select new
{
   ItemId = Result.Key,
   Metric1 = Result.Average(x => x.Metric1),
   Metric2 = Result.Average(x => x.Metric2)
}

var joinToItemsQuery = DB.Items 
Include Metrics
JOIN dateRangeQuery 
WHERE Items.Id == dateRangeQuery.ItemID

var orderQuery = joinToItemsQuery ORDERBY dateRangeQuery.Metric1
   SELECT Items

can then get the rank by finding the index of an item in the result of the orderQuery.
Writing the above has helped me to spot some unnecessary code, good old rubber duck.
as far as I can see there's no need to join Items with the dateRangeQuery so ill strip that out, should save some time.
The above has 2 run twice though, one for current daterange and one for previous daterange to get a comparison

I know you are looking for an algorithm solution, but 40s is a lot for a few thousands rows. I'd even say a million rows shouldn't take that long. Could you provide your current algorithm and your queries ?

Just to clarify there's roughly 4,000 "parent" rows and each one has a one to many relationship with another table for data/metrics that are gathered, which is currently over a million rows. In my example above there's the Item Table which has 4000 rows and a Metrics table which has 1 million + rows.
As for my current algorithm/queries ill get something together and edit my main post, additionally this is written in .Net Core and uses Entity framework

@AloisChristen have added some more detail to the OP

Your problem should go away if you just create the right index.
create unique index IdItemIdIdx on Metrics (Id, ItemId);

Now a week of data requires 28,000+ index lookups instead of scanning millions of rows over and over again.
If you want more efficient for large date range, change your Metrics table to CumulativeMetrics with columns:
Id  ItemId  CreatedDate CountOfDates SumOfMetric1 SumOfMetric2

Where all of these sums are over all time from the start through the CreatedDate.
Now you can calculate a date range by just looking at the rows for the start and end dates. So now we can fetch 3 dates per Id to get this and the previous date range. And that works no matter how big your date ranges are.
This makes large date ranges efficient. But note the caveats. You're now depending on this table having been correctly precalculated. You'll need some complexity about handling a date range that goes outside the date range of your table. But for that you get a nice speedup if someone is querying for a period of a month or a year.

Thanks, ill take a look at those suggestions. Think I may have ignored index as its already  in place, but potentially the wrong one.
When you say change your metrics table do you mean create a new table? to then query the date range on?

@Greg There is a world of difference that most don't realize between a concatenated index and two separate indexes. There is no way that you could have current performance with that concatenated index. And yes, this would be a new metric table. The sum in a date range is the cumulative sum at the end minus the cumulative sum just before. So one subtraction replaces a lot of addition.
